# Optimum encoding standard for flowplayer to play mp4

Tags: c#, video-streaming, flowplayer

I'm using flow player 3.1.1 for streaming videos to my browser.The videos are uploaded by the users and they may upload different formats. What will be solution to stream the videos as mp4 , what ever be the format they upload. I'm currently using ffmpeg commands.

```
ffmpeg -i "InputFile.mp4" -sameq -vcodec libx264 -r 35 -acodec libfaac -y  "OutputFile.mp4"
```

But video files of more size(say 100mb) are taking a minute more for laoding in to the flowplayer and buffering. I think the problem with my encoding.

Welcome your valuable Suggestions!!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem come from metadata.  ffmpeg put this data at the end of file, for a progressive download you must move this data at the begininng. You can use MP4Box or qt-faststart after ffmpeg process.
MP4Box -inter 1000 file.mp4 or qt-faststart in.mp4 out.mp4