# Best format available for jwplayer

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, jwplayer

I want the quality 360p, so I thought the format. Mp4
but is slow to load the video on my local server is faster but takes a long web. videos in flv is faster.
I use ffmpeg to convert videos

I'm using this command line to convert the file. mp4

```
ffmpeg-i "video.avi"-ar 22050-ab 32-f mp4 video.mp4
```

and also use this:

```
ffmpeg-i video.avi-vf scale = -1:360-c: v libx264-preset ultrafast video.mp4
```

I do not understand is slow to load, I think it may be the bitrate or file size, I do not know, by my testing the player expect to load the whole video to play, but not flv, so I do not understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimum encoding standard for flowplayer to play mp4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021659/optimum-encoding-standard-for-flowplayer-to-play-mp4)

Comment: Simply said, add `-movflags faststart` to your command or use `qt-faststart` on the MP4 files.

Comment: Yeah, this moves the MOOV ATOM to the front of the MP4 file, so that way the entire file doesn't have to be downloaded entirely first, before it can be played back.